# Post made by "anon", but present in a user's Top Network Posts list on other SE sites

Tags: bug, answers, profile-page, anonymous-user

This answer appears to be made by an anonymous user: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4036868/3079266

However, I accidentally saw a user with the answer listed in their Top Network Posts list on other SE sites where that user participates. I, however, can't see it in this user's post list on StackOverflow.

I never thought that posts made as an anonymous user could be associated with an account. Is this a bug?

Comment: I have no concrete proof and I know there's a specific reason, but my first gut reaction is that the user was probably deleted.

Comment: @Qix: I don't understand... do you mean that the user who made the post was deleted, and the post wound up associated with another user?

Comment: Can you link to the user in question?

Comment: @Qix: I thought that it is possible the user did not want people to know they made the post... but - oh well, here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/138112/p%C3%ABkka (Meta.SE profile, you can see the post); stackoverflow.com/users/187606/pekka-%EC%9B%83 (SO profile, post not there)

Comment: @Mints97 the second highest answer refers to Pekka. I don't think it's an issue. Very interesting though.

Comment: It very well could have been an administrative thing. He could have asked to have it disassociated with his account.

Comment: @GrantWinney: if it was, then not completely so. Actually, I never heard of SO having such a feature... I even remember someone in chat being sad that they can't disassociate a post from their account

Comment: @Qix: if it is an "administrative thing", they should take the Top Network Posts into account... So the issue still stands.

Comment: @Mints97 I didn't say otherwise. I'm just pointing out what might have happened.

Comment: It was a post of mine.

It was one of my highest-voted posts and I felt kind of embarrassed by it so I asked to be disassociated from it.

Comment: @Grant Somebody did now...

Comment: We are using the same data source as the network profile for this - you will notice that the network profile also shows this as the top answer for [Pekka](http://stackexchange.com/users/63368/pekka-%EC%9B%83)

Comment: Whoa. I think we need to fix disassociated posts showing on someone's profile.

Comment: @Pekka웃 that should be an answer.

Comment: @GrantWinney: I support this decision, but we'd have to wait for the bug to be fixed first. Deleting this post now would be pretty much useless as the disassociation is still broken...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It was a post of mine.

It was one of my highest-voted posts and I felt kind of embarrassed by it so I asked to be disassociated from it and a couple others.

I don't mind that Meta lurkers can still know it used to be a post of mine, so there's no need for any further action. I just figured that if at some point some stranger whose opinion matters to me (say, someone I apply with for a job  or whatever) should look at my profile, I don't want the top ten answers to be made up of simplistic "set this property to null" type answers. Pure vanity really.

Comment: I completely understand you. To tell the truth, this is what I originally suspected =) I guess that if you're fine with the question not fully disassociated, no need to wait for the admins to do something about it...

Comment: If any prospective employer held a highly upvoted answer against you, no matter how simplistic it may appear, then you don't want to work for them anyway.

Comment: @j08691 well, I don't think a lot of people would actively hold it *against* you, but if I saw a SO profile with a lot of such highly upvoted, simplistic answers, I would start asking myself what their reputation score actually has to say about their skills.

Comment: @Pekka웃: but... you do not have *many* highly upvoted and simplistic answers... you have only one... The rest are great and very detailed, especially the CSS Explosion one! =)

Comment: @Mints thanks! But there was a couple of really easy ones in the list that I asked the team to cull for me.

Comment: What I think you're saying is that you want to choose what posts you show off on your profile page.  Which is a perfectly reasonable feature request!

Comment: +1 to make it visible to employers and friends